# How to properly use sizing with Cocoa

Tags: cocoa, controls, sizing

ALL,

[NSSmallControlSize](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nssmallcontrolsize?language=objc) page has following explanation:

> This constant is for controls that cannot be resized in one direction,
>   such as push buttons, radio buttons, checkboxes, sliders, scroll bars,
>   pop-up buttons, tabs, and progress indicators. You should use a small
>   system font with a small control.

Is there any way to set the size for other controls? Namely NSComboBox.

Unfortunately the documentation is not talking about that. It's not even mentioning if it is at all possible.

TIA!

Comment: @Willeke, why did you say this? It is referenced an official Apple documentation, therefore it will never go away. Even after Apple remove the references to it from the code.

Comment: Apple does remove documentation and `NSSmallControlSize` is deprecated.

Comment: @Willeke, OK, got it. Thx for explanation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the page describes, the constant is for controls that cannot be resized in one direction. Combo boxes, like the listed controls, cannot be resized vertically. Therefore it makes sense that the constant would apply to combo boxes.

This can be quickly verified by creating a combo box in Interface Builder, clicking on the Size inspector, and setting its size to Small. Since this works, we can conclude that the small size is compatible with combo boxes.